# Apache ReverseProxy Questions - Server Fault or Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, scope

I have asked a question on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) about [Reverse Proxies](https://serverfault.com/questions/432436/reverseproxy-send-some-urls-to-another-server-for-preprocessing).  In this case I am not sure whether it's more appropriate to post it on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

I put it up on Server Fault because it's not a programming related question. However, I see several such questions on Stack Overflow also, e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852238/proxypassmatch-with-proxypassreverse).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of things on SO that should not be here. I agree with your view that this is off-topic and should be on Server Fault.

So just flag or vote to close the question as off-topic and it will be migrated as long as the question is less than 60 days old; if it is older, then it will just be closed as per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/166025).

See this [meta question re Apache configuration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6235/apache-configuration-htaccess-questions-esp-mod-rewrite-so-or-sf?rq=1).

Comment: Regarding your point "flag or vote the question as off topic and i will be migrated", this will not work for [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852238/proxypassmatch-with-proxypassreverse) mentioned by OP. As [questions older than 60 days are not eligible for migration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/166025).